# source control in vscode over 2,000 pending changes

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, node-modules, git-bash, web-frontend

At this point, I have over 2,000 pending changes. What should I do? I copied and past the non updated version of the json package after deleting the files and doing the course 5 times over just because of that. Should I save all of them to my git repository? or filter through them after I download them in my from npm to my json file. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a .gitignore file - and do you instruct it to ignore node_modules for instance?

Comment: I do, and I did not. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check the nature of those pending changes (diff)

- if those files are generated, add their parent folder to a `.gitignore`: see for instance [`gitignore.io node`](https://www.gitignore.io/api/node).
- if those files were tracked, but have only an eol difference (end of line: CRLF instead of LF), check if you can convert those files eol in order to avoid those diffs.